# Should "#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open" be included in .desktop files?

Tags: .desktop

Some people add the following line to a `.desktop` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
```

But when I checked files under the `/usr/share/applications/` in my debian sid, there's no such file that would include this line.

So the question is simple: should it be added or not?

Comment: This has to do with [.desktop file security](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xdg/2009-February/010209.html) and how _freedesktop.org_ people thought it should be implemented. For e.g. on all freedesktop compliant DE's that line is _automatically_ added when you _"mark"_ a `.desktop` file in ~/.local/share/applications _"as trusted"_ (e.g [here](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/desktop-devel-list/2009-February/msg00132.html)'s how gnome implemented this ..). So this is not a matter of _"If you don't need it to be executable then you don't need it."_

Comment: That should have been an answer, not a comment on the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By having a `#!` line then the `.desktop` file can be made *executable* and run directly (e.g. from a command line, or some file browsers).

The idea behind wrapping with `env` is to handle different OS's where `xdg-open` might be in different directories.  For example, on Debian the program is in `/usr/bin/xdg-open` but on another OS it might be elsewhere.  The location of `env` is pretty much fixed and this construct will effectively result in `$PATH` being searched for the `xdg-open` program.

On my Debian install no file in `/usr/share/applications` is marked executable and none of them have a `#!` line.

So if you want your `.desktop` file to be executable then you need a `#!` and wrapping it with `env` will help in portability.  If you don't need it to be executable then you don't need it.

Comment: Many KDE applications have executable `.desktop` files on debian to. You can find them (if installed) with `$ find /usr/share/applications/ -executable -type f`